# Custom copy assignment operator crashes the program (C++)

Tags: c++, image, sdl, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

I'm creating a custom class for automaticly cleaning up memory. The class contains a pointer to an SDL_Surface object and calls it's refcount when needed. The problem is when I implement the custom copy assigment operator the system crashes with the following code:

"Unhandled exception at 0x771a15de in xyz.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd04."

and the object attribute "address" suddenly gets the value "0x0000ffff ", whilst using the default copy assignment operator it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: I strongly suggest you make use of `std::shared_ptr` instead of doing reference counting manually.

Comment: Look into the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for an easy way to get correct behavior. jrok is right though: `shared_ptr` with custom deleter would solve this issue even better.

Comment: `SDL_FreeSurface` will decrement the refcount, and when called on a null pointer, is a no-op.  So there is no need, (in your destructor or your assignment operator), to check for NULL, decrement the refcount, or compare the refcount to 0.  Just call `SDL_FreeSurface`.  See the second to last example of this page: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, that's probably the source of your error.  You're decrementing the refcount, then calling SDL_FreeSurface, which decrements it again.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I think you should make your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the refcount incorrectly.  `SDL_FreeSurface` will decrement the refcount, and when called on a null pointer, is a no-op.  So, your assignment operator should look like this:

```
const Image& Image::operator=(const Image& other){
    if (img != other.img){
        SDL_FreeSurface(img);
        img = other.img;
        if (img != NULL)
            img->refcount++;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And your destructor should look like this:

```
Image::~Image(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
}
```

Also, in your default constructor, you should initialize img to a null pointer.

```
Image::Image() :img(NULL) {}
```

See the second to last example on this page: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, I should have noticed that! It now works like a charm!